Primary key constraint error while inserting default in `id` column,
My application trying to insert new entity into DB (url=jdbc:h2:mem:db) and I get following error:
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON MY_TABLE(ID) ( /* key:10 */ CAST(10 AS BIGINT), UUID '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')"; SQL statement:
insert into my_table (id, account_id) values (default, ?) [23505-214]

My table declared as:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id                              BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id                      UUID NOT NULL
)

Unfortunately I can't provide minimal reproducible example because error happens only when I run big test suite.
It is correlated with other test that also insert in that table. Test are NOT run in parralel.
Am I right that "PRIMARY KEY ON MY_TABLE(ID)" means that this is primary key violation? My table have other uniq constrains so I'm not sure.
EDIT
Here is minimal example to reproduce:
-- create
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  val BIGINT NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, VAL) VALUES (2, 99);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, VAL) VALUES (default, 99);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, VAL) VALUES (default, 99);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, VAL) VALUES (default, 99);



You use legacy PostgreSQL-specific syntax (deprecated in both PostgreSQL and H2) in definition of your table, modern applications should use BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY instead. And both these database systems throw an exception about PK violation. The SQL Standard actually requires such behavior, so it isn't a bug.

H2 does not allow to insert value of sequential primary key and use default at same time.
Not sure if this is a bug or feature.
Cause of problem located in org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex#add.
When row.setKey(lastKey.incrementAndGet()) is executed it doesn't take into account that this value may be already inserted in table manually.

Internal key of the row is not related to your problem.

@EvgenijRyazanov it does. When Row old = (Row)map.putIfAbsent(rowKey, row) return not null exception happens. rowKey defined as long rowKey = row.getKey(). You can check in source code, I gave the reference.

H2 simply uses a value of id column as an internal row number in your case. An attempt to insert a duplicate value into PK column throws an exception, how it is implemented internally doesn't really matter. Generators of identity columns don't check existing values in the table (unless you use MySQL and its identity columns, they work in the different way).

As far as I understand you defend "Internal key of the row is not related to your problem" by saying that is not a problem. Technically true :)
